# Conditional Statement Where all Values must be Satisfied

Tags: xaml, if-statement, conditional-statements

fairly new to .xaml conditions and I wanted to make sure I was going in the right direction when it comes to setting them up. I have a test activity that should only skip under the following conditions:

Type == TestType

FirstOfKind == True

FirstOfKindTesting = True

I only want for the activity to skip if all of these conditions are met, so for example if the settings are:

Type == TestType

FirstOfKind == true

FirstOfKindTesting = False

Originally I set it up this way:

`(!string.EqualsSettings[Names.Type], "TestType", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &amp;&amp; !Settings.IsTrue("FirstOfKind") &amp;&amp; !Settings.IsTrue("FirstofKindTesting"))`

That however made it so that if one of the values is true the activity skips, so I've tweaked it to be the following:

`!(string.EqualsSettings[Names.Type], "TestType", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase &amp;&amp; Settings.IsTrue("FirstOfKind") &amp;&amp; Settings.IsTrue("FirstofKindTesting"))`

I feel like having the ! operator on the outside of the full statement rather than in front of each portion should fix the logic. Is this correct? Is there a more efficent way to get the result I need? Thanks so much in advance! :)